# Convenience initializer in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, class, initialization

So I have started doing some tutorials on Xcode with objective-c and I have noticed one thing.

If I am creating object I have to allocate it and initialize it, right?
something like:

```
NSObject *objet = [[NSObject alloc] init];
```

or with designated initializer:

```
MyObject *object = [[MyObject alloc] initWithAttribute:attribute];
```

After few tutorials I learned about something called "convenient initializers" which is basically same "just" without keyword alloc, right?

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"string", nil];
```

My question is: why are designated initializers always instance methods (-) and convenience initializers are always class methods (+)?

Thank you

Comment: To make them more convenient? :D

Comment: ^ Could not have said it better.

Comment: @holex what are you talking about? Because they definitely are class(+) methods which makes them more convenient by not having to call a class method (`alloc`) then an instance method (`initXXX`).

Comment: @Joe, about the convenience initialisers, of course.

Comment: Ok, your referring to semantics, the fact they are called convenience constructors and not *convenience initializers*.

Comment: Yup, I lost the point.

Comment: @Joe, I see what cause the issue here... I'm talking about _Swift_ not ObjectiveC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A designated initializer is one that all other init methods call through to. In order to properly define a subclass that does its own initialization, you need to override its superclass's designated initializer.

The other kind of method you identified here isn't called a convenience initializer — it's a convenience *constructor*. The name refers to the fact that a convenience constructor both creates and initializes an object for you. And unlike with objects that you created yourself with `alloc`, you don't own the object returned from a convenience constructor, so you don't need to release when in manual retain/release mode. (Typically it's autoreleased, but this is an implementation detail.)

Comment: +1 for paragraph #2,  but why must one always override designated init if the subclass has nothing new to say about it, e.g. if nil is the desired initial value for some added property?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't have constructors as such.  A class method that gives you a new instance of an object is a factory method.

Comment: @JeremyP: "Convenience constructors" actually is the idiomatic term for these methods in Objective-C. They aren't what C++ or other languages call constructors, but that's what they are traditionally called in Objective-C.

Comment: I've never herds anybody call them convenience constructors in Objective-C.

Comment: @JeremyP: Well, if you're curious, here's [a search on the Cocoa mailing list archives](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/search/1?q=convenience+constructor&l=cocoa) that shows lots of very experienced Cocoa developers, including much of Apple's Cocoa team, calling it that. Apple have radically changed their documentation format over the past couple of years and no longer include the term there, but they used to feature it very prominently in the memory management section.

Comment: @Chuck No, they never featured it prominently in their documentation.  Objective-C doesn't have constructors (and a lot of your search results don't really support your point either).  Anyway, I'm not going to argue this with you anymore because it is a fairly minor point of terminology and not really worth the time for either of us.

Answer (score 2):

The class methods (+) are not considered initializers of any sort. They are more commonly called factory methods. In the simple case, the implementation of these methods call `alloc` and some flavor of `init` to create an instance of an object, and then return the object. I think one of reasons they became common had to do with easily providing autoreleased objects in pre-ARC days, though others could probably address that aspect better than I.

Initializers in objective-C are always instance methods (-) and are simply methods that follow the convention of starting with `init`. Convenience initializers are in contrast to the [*designated initializer*](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH6-SW3). The designated initializer is one init method that you choose as the main one that is most fully responsible for initializing the state of the object, and the other initializers can call the designated initializer instead of a superclass initializer.

All initializers are designed to be used in conjunction with `alloc`; `alloc` allocates and initializes the memory required for the object, and the initializer sets up the beginning state of the object's fields, properties, etc., possibly based on values provided by in parameters sent from he caller.

Comment: Why don't we just agree to call it a "convenience create-and-initialize-and-autorelease-the-object thingie"?

Comment: @HotLicks that fits in nicely with the verbosity of Cocoa :)

Comment: Note also, that [NSObject alloc] allocates the necessary memory and returns an instance, so You can call init later and initialize that instance with the initial data

Answer (score 1):

The convenience factory methods, e.g.

```
NSArray *array = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"string", nil];
```

will, as part of their implementation, call `alloc` and the regular constructor for you. They're not any special workaround to avoid calling alloc (usually; in some special cases they might return a singleton e.g. NSNumber). You're still going through the allocate and initialize steps.

They're simply more convenient & compact to read & write.

FWIW, the above array creation is *even more convenient* to write now: `@[@"string"]`.